# convert data to JSON array

Tags: php, android

i am trying to use the push notification in google cloud messages and i am passing an array om registration ids, but for some reason i got the following error:

```
Field "data" must be a JSON array: You have just invited to play 'Soccer'
```

this is the part that i am trying to pass:

```
"registred_ids":["APA91bF9itasGCSK8NbD9u5GJWnEmbWCdS0sEn_xxRVbVpfI0_3FKkvxVBr5xtdE26VZgOO8rCBpf4CaAzHUbMj7PmmDxqpdbWO6VBrPB8dW4CPqPovJbnB_p1Ha_fuwyf8SnOqgOFajK8HEdiZO65qUljO2wCuuDQ"]
```

not the code of the gcm is :

```
      <?php


    class GCM {

        function __construct() {

        }
        /**
         * Sending Push Notification
         */
        public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
            // include config
            include_once 'connection.php';

            // Set POST variables
            $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

            $fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
                'data' => $message,
            );

            $headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' .GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
            // Open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

            // Execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);
            echo $result;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

and the code which passing the registration ids is:

```
 <?php
include 'response_process.php';
include 'gcm.php';


class CreateEvent implements ResponseProcess {



    public function dataProcess($dblink)
    {
        $output = array();
        $sport = $_POST["sport_type"];
        $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$_POST["date"])));
        $s_time =$_POST["s_time"];
        $e_time = $_POST["e_time"];
        $lon = $_POST["lon"];
        $lat = $_POST["lat"];
        $event_type = $_POST["event_type"];
        $max_p = $_POST["max_participants"];
        $sched = $_POST["scheduled"];
        $gen = $_POST["gender"];
        $min_age = $_POST["minAge"];
        $manager = $_POST["manager"];



        $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE (event.longtitude = '$lon' AND event.latitude = '$lat')
                AND event.event_date = '$date' And ((event.start_time BETWEEN '$s_time' AND '$e_time') OR (event.end_time BETWEEN '$s_time' AND '$e_time'))";

        //AND (event.start_time = '$s_time' AND event.end_time = '$e_time')


        //check time and place of the event
        $result_q = mysqli_query($dblink,$query) or die (mysqli_error($dblink));
        if(!$result_q)
        {
            $output["flag"]= "select failed";
            $output["msg"] = $result_q;
            return json_encode($output);
        }
        //case date and time are available
        else {
            $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result_q);
            if ($no_of_rows < 1) {
                $output["flag"] = "success";
                $output["msg"] = "insert event";

                $result = mysqli_query($dblink, "INSERT into event(manager_id,kind_of_sport,event_date,start_time,end_time,longtitude,latitude,private,gender,min_age,max_participants,current_participants,scheduled,event_status)
             VALUES ('$manager','$sport','$date','$s_time','$e_time','$lon','$lat','$event_type','$gen','$min_age','$max_p','1','$sched','1')") or die (mysqli_error($dblink));
                if (!$result) {
                    $output["flag"] = "failed to create event";
                    // return (json_encode($output));

                }
                else{

                    if(isset($_POST["invitedUsers"])){
                        $query_id = "SELECT id From event WHERE event.event_date = '$date' and event.start_time = '$s_time' and event.end_time = '$e_time'";
                        $event_s_res = mysqli_query($dblink,$query_id) or die (mysqli_error($dblink));
                        if(!$event_s_res)
                        {
                            $output["flag"] = "failed";
                            $output["msg"] = "Event id not found";
                        }
                        else{
                            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($event_s_res);
                            $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($event_s_res);
                            if($no_of_rows > 1 || $no_of_rows == 0)
                            {
                                $output["flag"] = "failed";
                                $output["msg"] = "Event id not found";
                            }
                            else{
                                $event_id = $row["id"];
                                $json = $_POST["jsoninvited"];
                                $json = json_decode($json);
                                $output["size_invited"] = count($json);
                                $query_users = "SELECT id,gcm_id From users WHERE ";
                                $i=0;

                                $size_of_param = (count($json));
                                foreach($json as $user) {
                                    if ($i < $size_of_param - 1)
                                        // add a space at end of this string
                                        $query_users .= "users.mobile = '".$user."' or ";
                                    else {
                                        // and this one too
                                        $query_users .= "users.mobile = '".$user."' ";
                                        $output["users"][] = $user['mobile'];
                                    }
                                    $i++;
                                    $output["index"]=$i;
                                }
                                $output["user_query"]= $query_users;

                                $event_user_s_res = mysqli_query($dblink,$query_users) or die (mysqli_error($dblink));
                                if(!$event_user_s_res)
                                {
                                    $output["flag"] = "failed";
                                    $output["msg"] = "user id not found";
                                }

                                $insert_query = "INSERT into attending (event_id,user_id,status) VALUES ";
                                $i=0;
                                $status = "deny";
                               $registration_ids = array();
                                while($row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($event_user_s_res))
                                {
                                    $registration_ids[$i]=$row_user["gcm_id"];
                                    if($i<$size_of_param - 1)
                                        $insert_query .= "('" .$event_id. "','" .$row_user["id"]. "','" .$status. "'), ";
                                    else
                                        $insert_query .= "('".$event_id."','".$row_user["id"]."','".$status."') ";
                                    $i++;
                                }
                                $insert_query_res = mysqli_query($dblink,$insert_query) or die (mysqli_error($dblink));
                                if(!$insert_query_res)
                                {
                                    $output["flag"] = "failed";
                                    $output["msg"] = "failed to insert to attending table";
                                }else{
                                    $output["id_query"]= $insert_query;
                                    $output["registred_ids"] = $registration_ids;
                                    $output["msg"] = "success to insert into attending";
                                    $gcm = new GCM();
                                    $message = "You have just invited to play '".$sport."'";
                                    $output["gcm_message"]=$message;
                                    $gcm_res = $gcm->send_notification($registration_ids,$message);
                                    $output["gcm_res"] = $gcm_res;

                                } //els of $insert_query_res
                            } //else of  $no_of_rows > 1 || $no_of_rows == 0


                        } // else  of $event_s_res
                    } //if isset($_POST["invitedUsers"]

                } // if $result


            } // if $no_of_rows < 1
            else {
                $output["flag"] = "failed";
                $output["msg"] = "Place is already occupied in this time";
            }
        }
        return json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this-

```
$fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => array("message" => $message),
        );
```

Comment: when i try your solution before the fix i get this results: {"multicast_id":845667462821******,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446021765558675%e63ae1e0f9fd7ecd"}]} does its says its worked?

Answer (score -1):

It says the data field needs to be an array, but you are setting it to $message, which is a string, not an array.

Comment: That's not a helpful answer. it does not solve the question.

Comment: It looks like the Author of the question has a problem to understand the error message, so this answer may help.

Answer (score -1):

```
Field "data" must be a JSON array: You have just invited to play 'Soccer'
```

This means the value passed in data node is not a json.
Encoding $message into json will fix the error.

Comment: Please post part of the altered code to illustrate it. No, the down vote is not mine.